# How to prevent an application from connecting to a network with iptables?

Tags: iptables

I have read the manual page of iptables in terminal, but it has complicated syntax and I don't fully understand how to use options like: user, user ID, UUID and so on.

Suppose my username is foobar and I want to prevent an application from connecting to any kind of network. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can block all traffic for a user *BLOCKUSER* using the `owner` iptables module.

```
iptables -I INPUT -m owner --uid-owner BLOCKUSER -j REJECT
iptables -I OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner BLOCKUSER -j REJECT
```

You can also use the `DROP` target instead of `REJECT` but this would only extend 
cause delays due to timeouts (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109462/15241) for more discussion).

It could also be convenient/necessary to allow access to the [loopback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback#Virtual_loopback_interface) device:

```
iptables -I INPUT  -m owner --uid-owner BLOCKUSER ! -i lo -j REJECT
iptables -I OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner BLOCKUSER ! -o lo -j REJECT
```

---

About your questions:

- **user** is the username which you use to login and output of the `whoami` command.
- **UID** is the numerical user ID (most time you can simply use
  the username instead of the UID, you can display it with the `id` command).
- **UUID** is a [Universally unique identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) and not directly used in iptables. (`--uuid-owner` is a typo)

Comment: The owner match is only available for the OUTPUT and POSTROUTING chain! See man iptables-extensions for details!