# Allow specific port through iptables

Tags: debian, iptables

I am new with iptables. I created a script that resets (reset.sh) iptables and other script (ip-chains.sh) creates chains like input output chains. In the same scipr (ip-chains.sh) at the bottom I created a rule just to test to allow incoming and outgoing port 2121 which I am using for FTP.

The problem is when I run reset script I can access FTP server, but when I run ip-chains.sh script I can't. I am confused because I have the rule in the same script file to allow traffic on port 2121.

I am using eth1 to connect to FTP server 192.168.1.0 and eth2 to connect to client machine. Here is my ip-chains.sh scipt:

```
    #!/bin/bash

#Flush tables and set policies to drop

iptables -F

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

#Create Logging Chain for accepted packets on INPUT CHAIN

iptables -N accept-input

#Rules for  accept-input chain

iptables -A accept-input -j LOG --log-prefix "INPUT-ACCEPTED "
iptables -A accept-input -j ACCEPT

#Create Logging Chain for dropped packets on INPUT CHAIN

iptables -N drop-input

#Rules for  drop-input chain

iptables -A drop-input -j LOG --log-prefix "INPUT-DROPPED "
iptables -A drop-input -j DROP

#Create Logging Chain for accepted packets on OUTPUT CHAIN

iptables -N accept-output

#Rules for  accept-output chain

iptables -A accept-output -j LOG --log-prefix "OUTPUT-ACCEPTED "
iptables -A accept-output -j ACCEPT

#Create Logging Chain for dropped packets on OUTPUT CHAIN

iptables -N drop-output

#Rules for  drop-output chain

iptables -A drop-output -j LOG --log-prefix "OUTPUT-DROPPED "
iptables -A drop-output -j ACCEPT


#Allow port 2121

iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -s 0/0 --dport 2121 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j accept-input
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p tcp -d 0/0 --sport 2121 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j accept-input

iptables -A INPUT -i eth2 -p tcp -s 0/0 --dport 2121 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j accept-input
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth2 -p tcp -d 0/0 --sport 2121 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j accept-input

#Log all DROPPED traffic

iptables -A INPUT -j drop-input
iptables -A OUTPUT -j drop-output

iptables -L -n
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, when you flush your rules with `iptables -F` you flush all your rules, but not your policy! So if you have `policy DROP` you can easily get locked out of your system!

Usually is safer set `policy ACCEPT` with a `DROP` as last rule of the chain. Or while you're working remotely to your firewall set up a `cron` job to set `policy ACCEPT` and `iptables -F` every five or ten minutes; in this way you are sure to have access to your system in any case.

In your script you have `iptables -p FORWARD DROP` and there are no rules from `eth1` to `eth2` and viceversa. You have to set `iptables -p FORWARD ACCEPT` or add some rules to the forward chain to solve your problem, for example:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -i eth1 -o eth2 -s 2121 -d 2121 -j ACCEPT;
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -i eth2 -o eth1 -s 2121 -d 2121 -j ACCEPT;
```

Comment: thanks for answer. I would like to know how I would make my firewall work without changing `iptables -p FORWARD DROP` to `iptables -p FORWARD ACCEPT`.

Comment: [Use REJECT in the last rule rather than DROP](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109459/is-it-better-to-set-j-reject-or-j-drop-in-iptables).

Answer (score 0):

use -v to see where packets have landed...

```
iptables --list -n -v
```

Comment: when I run above command: I see few packets dropped and those are from client trying to reach FTP server.

Comment: try adding;

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT